# Uninstall OSX-gcc-installer without first installing Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode, gcc

Is there a way that I can uninstall `osx-gcc-installer` without first having to install Xcode, then run `sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools —mode=all` ?

I installed it on Mountain Lion, and I want to get rid of it so my `CLI` tools will work to install [Octopress](http://www.octopress.org).

Is there a script or command that will help me totally remove `osx-gcc-installer` from my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I'm seeing in the developer's scripts [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/blob/master/GCC-10.7.pmdoc/index.xml), it looks like he is recommending that you install Xcode over the top of his "osx-gcc-installer" to be able to uninstall...At that point, you can run the uninstall-devtools script...

From the developer:

> If something doesn't work as expected, feel free to install Xcode over this installation.
>
> Once installed, you can remove Xcode completely with the following:
>
> ```
> sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools -mode=all
> ```

Alternately, you can copy and paste the actual script content into a blank text document (maybe named "uninstall-devtools"), make it editable (`chmod 755 uninstall-devtools`), and then execute it (`sudo ./uninstall-devtools -mode=all`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
####################################################################################################
#
# Copyright (c) 2002-2011 Apple, Inc.
# Xcode 4.2
#
# NAME
#     uninstall-devtools -- Meta-script for running the various devtools uninstaller scripts.
#
# SYNOPSIS
#     sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
#     sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=xcodedir
#     sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=unixdev
#     sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=systemsupport
#
# Where the specified 'mode' value invokes the following devtools uninstaller scripts:
#
#     all:
#         /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
#         /Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools
#         /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder
#
#     xcodedir:
#         /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder
#
#     unixdev:
#         /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
#
#     systemsupport:
#         /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
#         /Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools
#
# The default value for 'mode' is 'all'.
#
# DESCRIPTION
#     This command runs the appropriate devtools uninstaller scripts according to the usage
#     specified on the command line.
####################################################################################################

my $do_nothing     = 0;
my $verbose        = 0;
my $warning        = 0;
my $debug          = 0;
my $help           = 0;
my $mode           = '';

get_options(
    'do-nothing' => \$do_nothing,
    'verbose' => \$verbose,
    'warning' => \$warning,
    'debug' => \$debug,
    'help' => \$help,
    'mode' => \$mode,
);

####################################################################################################

if ($help == 1) {
    print("Usage: $0 --mode=<all|xcodedir|unixdev|systemsupport>\n");
print <<"END";
This is a meta-script which invokes one or more of the devtools
uninstaller scripts, depending on which mode you select.

The recognized modes are:
all:
    /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
    /Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools
    /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder

xcodedir:
    /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder

unixdev:
    /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools

systemsupport:
    /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools
    /Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools

The default value for 'mode' is 'all'.
END
    exit(0);
}

####################################################################################################
# Determine if we are authorized to uninstall the devtools packages.
####################################################################################################

$| = 1;
if (($do_nothing == 0) && ($< != 0)) {
    die("ERROR: Must be run with root permissions -- prefix command with 'sudo'.\n");
}

####################################################################################################

my $uninstaller_script = $0;
my ($uninstaller_dir,$uninstaller_script_basename) = parse_name($uninstaller_script);
if ($uninstaller_dir eq '.') {
    die("ERROR: Must change to another directory before running this script, since the current directory is about to be deleted.\n");
}
my ($developer_dir,$developer_dir_basename) = parse_name($uninstaller_dir);

####################################################################################################

my @flags = ();
if ($do_nothing == 1) {
    push(@flags,'--do-nothing');
}
if ($verbose == 1) {
    push(@flags,'--verbose');
}
if ($warning == 1) {
    push(@flags,'--warning');
}
if ($debug == 1) {
    push(@flags,'--debug');
}

if (($mode eq '') || ($mode eq 'all')) {
    run_uninstaller_script("/Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools",\@flags);
    run_uninstaller_script("/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools",\@flags);
    run_uninstaller_script("$developer_dir/Library/uninstall-developer-folder",\@flags);
} elsif ($mode eq 'xcodedir') {
    run_uninstaller_script("$developer_dir/Library/uninstall-developer-folder",\@flags);
} elsif ($mode eq 'unixdev') {
    run_uninstaller_script("/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools",\@flags);
} elsif ($mode eq 'systemsupport') {
    run_uninstaller_script("/Library/Developer/4.2/uninstall-devtools",\@flags);
    run_uninstaller_script("/Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools",\@flags);
} else {
    die("Usage: $0 --mode=<all|xcodedir|shared|systemsupport>\n");
}
print("IMPORTANT: If you are going to install a previous version of the Developer Tools, be sure to restart the machine after installing.\n");

####################################################################################################

sub get_options {
    while (@_) {
    my $option_name = shift(@_);
    my $option_pointer = shift(@_);

    foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
        if ($arg =~ /^--$option_name/) {
        my ($arg_name,$arg_value) = split(/=/,$arg);
                $arg_value = 1 if (!$arg_value);
        $$option_pointer = $arg_value;
        }
    }
    }
}

####################################################################################################

sub parse_name {
   my $name = shift;
   my ($dir_name,$base_name) = ($name =~ m{^(.*/)?(.*)}s);
   $dir_name =~ s|(.*)/$|$1|s;
   return ($dir_name,$base_name);
}

####################################################################################################

sub run_uninstaller_script {
    my $script = shift;
    my $flagsref = shift;

    if (-x $script) {
        my @args = ();
        push(@args,$script);
        foreach my $flag (@$flagsref) {
            push(@args,$flag);
        }

        system({$args[0]} @args);
    }
}

####################################################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, osx-gcc-installer has overwritten some system files which are actually 'shims', so even if you run that script to delete those files it overwrote, you will need to restore the original system files.

First, run the script suggested in the other answer. Then:

Either you can download and reinstall your OSX again, from the App Store.
Or you could download the OSX Mavericks shims from this torrent, and copy them into your /usr/bin folder, overwriting those that are there:

https://archive.org/details/completely_uninstall_osx-gcc-installer

Note: This was the solution I found for OSX Mavericks (10.9) but it might work for you as well. Be careful in using these Mavericks /usr/bin files in your Mountain Lion. So you might want to download Mountain Lion again and use a procedure such as this: http://magnemg.tumblr.com/post/113260971290/how-to-extract-only-the-necessary-usr-bin-files

PS: This answer should include everything you need to know, but if you still need more details, see: http://magnemg.tumblr.com/post/113251602430/how-to-completely-uninstall-osx-gcc-installer

Comment: Please provide an answer here (not only link), because it might be broken in the future.

Comment: Ok, done. I updated the answer with all the necessary info. I had to write it pretty high level, so as to not basically copy-paste my entire blog post into it.

Comment: (I'll delete this comment tomorrow). I rejected your edit to my answer about creating a new empty Textedit file because you wrote 'newer versions' when it should have been 'older versions'. It was a good suggestion otherwise, and I cleaned up my answer a little.